# How to check Haskell infix operator precedence

Tags: haskell, ghci, infix-operator

I can see the type of an infix operator in GHCi with :t like so:

```
>:t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

How can i see the operator precedence in GHCi?  is that possible?

Also, bonus question, is there a way to see the source of these prelude functions through ghci?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`:i` (`:info`).

```
[Prelude]
> :i (+)
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
        -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
infixl 6 +
```

Comment: Thanks -- anyway to see the source from GHCI, or is that a pipedream?

Comment: @Adam To see the source, you can't use ghci (yet). The haddocks should link to syntax-coloured sources.

Comment: Note that you can use hoogle (http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or hayoo (http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) to easily access the haddock documentation of a function.